# How to disable Jest `console.log` tags

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have some NodeJS logging done via `console.log()` internally (its actually [loglevel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loglevel)) and as I see it, Jest tags console.log output with `console.log ../path/to/string/with/console.log/call:line#` for whatever reason:

[image]

I haven't found any related options in the docs. How can I disable it?

Comment: Please check if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563578/1492977) is helpful to you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove logging the origin line in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555568/remove-logging-the-origin-line-in-jest)

Comment: @jonrsharpe you are posting a link to a question, not an answer. Also, I've already mentioned one of the answers to the question you linked in my own answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51588150/216042.

Comment: Yes, that's how duplicates work. And I can see that, this is why it's obviously a duplicate.

Comment: well, duplicate or not the linked question still does not have an answer to my question

Comment: @jonrsharpe btw I flagged the question you linked as duplicate, thanks for the heads up

Comment: That's exactly **not** what should happen, this question should be closed as a duplicate of the other one, so the *next* person with the same problem gets sent to the answers there (which it does have, you just don't want to use them). What you're suggesting with that dupe proposal is that people going to *that* question be send *here*, which makes absolutely no sense. I don't think you've understood how duplicates work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh, I thought duplicates are identical entities created *after* the original one. My question is the original one, it has been created two months before the duplicate. Also I would argue that answers in the duplicate have much value since they basically suggest to break Jest to mute the `console.log` tags.

Comment: *When* they were created doesn't much matter, we don't want to send people to worse content just because it's *older*. See e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315472/3001761. Those answers don't suggest "breaking Jest", but even so do you really think that the answer below (basically "don't use Jest") is more useful to the next person that wants to suppress that part of Jest's output? In general dupes exist to get people to existing content that helps them, to reduce duplication and keep related content in one place: it doesn't have to be word-for-word the same.

Comment: @jonrsharpe "do you really think that the answer below (basically "don't use Jest") is more useful" -- absolutely! It saved me a ton of valuable time at that moment. For developing with React - you use Jest without questions. Developing server-side Node.js - questionable, unless you are okay with some annoying this and that. So yes, I claim my answer is still a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Anders Carstensen, I've looked at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555568/remove-logging-the-origin-line-in-jest#51563578) you mentioned and it says:

> Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-util/src/get_console_output.js) for Jest, it doesn't seem like there is a neat way to turn those messages off.

Not an option for me to write my own console, so I'll just stick with Mocha/Sinon for now.

Answer (score 13):

**IMPORTANT**:

I had the curiosity to take a look to the answer mentioned in the first answer, wich it says:

> Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-util/src/get_console_output.js) for Jest, it doesn't seem like there is a
> neat way to turn those messages off.

And I noticed an **update** marked on the answer and **resolves the problem**.

**Solution**:

Just add this code to your test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    global.console = require('console');
  });
```

Comment: This seems to also work as a stand-alone command in a setup file. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

Create a global configuration test file e.g. `src/test/config.js`, add this line to that file:

```
jest.spyOn(console, "log").mockImplementation();
```

add this to jest config:

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./src/test/config.js']
```

you can also use that file for global cleanup, before/after each etc

Answer (score 0):

[tslalamam answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68950385/3910375) code not worked for me, but this one works

### 1: Create a file with this code (e.g. config.js)

```
import console from "console"
global.console = console
```

### 2: Add this line to your jest.config.js

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./config.js"]
```

#### Before:

[image: How to disable Jest console.log tags]

#### After:

[image: How to disable Jest console.log tags]

Enjoi!