# Remove logging the origin line in Jest

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, jestjs

Jest has this feature to log the line that outputs to `console` methods.

In some cases, this can become annoying:

```
  console.log _modules/log.js:37
  ℹ login.0 screenshot start

  console.time _modules/init.js:409
  login.0.screenshot: 0.33ms

  console.time _modules/init.js:394
  0 | login.0: 0.524ms

  console.log _modules/log.js:37
  ℹ login.1 screenshot start
```

Any idea how I can turn it off?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Jest \`console.log\` tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942189/how-to-disable-jest-console-log-tags)

Comment: @yentsun clearly not; that only has one answer, which quotes an answer below and concludes with just not using Jest. A duplicate should take the reader *to* answers, not *from* them.

Comment: The question is still a duplicate of the older question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### None of the above options worked for me.

The (current) simplest solution is this:

#### 1: Create a file with this code (e.g. config.js)

```
import console from "console"
global.console = console
```

#### 2: Add this line to your jest.config.js

```
setupFilesAfterEnv: ["./config.js"]
```

##### Before:

[image: Remove logging the origin line in Jest]

##### After:

[image: Remove logging the origin line in Jest]

Enjoi!

Comment: are those files created in the root folder? It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 21):

With Jest 24.3.0 or higher, you can do this in pure TypeScript by adding the following to a Jest setup file configured in `setupFilesAfterEnv`:

```
import { CustomConsole, LogType, LogMessage } from '@jest/console';

function simpleFormatter(type: LogType, message: LogMessage): string {
    const TITLE_INDENT = '    ';
    const CONSOLE_INDENT = TITLE_INDENT + '  ';

    return message
        .split(/\n/)
        .map(line => CONSOLE_INDENT + line)
        .join('\n');
}

global.console = new CustomConsole(process.stdout, process.stderr, simpleFormatter);
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in JavaScript? I have a simple ES6 project that does not use Babel or TypeScript.

Comment: This option does not work in ES6 projects. (but the next comment do)

Answer (score 12):

Jest injects custom console implementation that is based on extendable [`Console` class](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_class_console) into test global scope. Normally it provides useful debugging information alongside printed message that answers the question where potentially unwanted output comes from.

In case this is undesirable for some reason, a simple way to retrieve default `console` implementation is to import it from Node built-in module.

Can be done for specific console calls:

```
let console = require('console');    
...
console.log(...)
```

For many of them that occur inside a range of tests:

```
const jestConsole = console;

beforeEach(() => {
  global.console = require('console');
});

afterEach(() => {
  global.console = jestConsole;
});
```

And so on.

Comment: When tests are run in parallel (the default behaviour of jest), Jest uses its custom console implementation to batch the test output and print it all at once after each test. Your approach breaks this, causing the test output to be interleaved.

Comment: Thanks for argumented downvote. It's true that the output will be interweaved and I didn't state the opposite. It's up to a developer if it's desirable but I assume it makes sense if the intention is to provide vanilla console output, it's harder to keep track of logs if they don't appear in real time. I don't fully understand the problem with origin line from the OP but from my experience delayed logs can be annoying for a long test.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67861269/1993761. Just tried it and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** For newer versions of Jest, see Harald Wellmann's answer.

---

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-util/src/get_console_output.js) for Jest, it doesn't seem like there is a neat way to turn those messages off.

However, one possible solution could be to write your own Console. Here I have used [Console.js](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-util/src/Console.js) from Jest as a starting ground, and then created `SimpleConsole` which does what you need (I have removed some terminal coloring features for simplicity, but you could just add them yourself).

Once added to your project, you can overwrite Jest's normal console with your own before running the tests:

```
const { SimpleConsole } = require('./SimpleConsole');
global.console = new SimpleConsole(process.stdout, process.stderr);
```

I have made a [REPL](https://repl.it/repls/CompassionateMassiveActivecontent) that shows it in action.

The source code for `SimpleConsole`:

```
const path = require('path');
const assert = require('assert');
const {format} = require('util');
const {Console} = require('console');

function simpleFormatter() {
  const TITLE_INDENT = '    ';
  const CONSOLE_INDENT = TITLE_INDENT + '  ';

  return (type, message) => {
    message = message
      .split(/\n/)
      .map(line => CONSOLE_INDENT + line)
      .join('\n');

    return (
      message +
      '\n'
    );
  };
};

class SimpleConsole extends Console {
  constructor(stdout, stderr, formatBuffer) {
    super(stdout, stderr);
    this._formatBuffer = formatBuffer || simpleFormatter();
    this._counters = {};
    this._timers = {};
    this._groupDepth = 0;
  }

  _logToParentConsole(message) {
    super.log(message);
  }

  _log(type, message) {
    if (process.stdout.isTTY) {
      this._stdout.write('\x1b[999D\x1b[K');
    }
    this._logToParentConsole(
      this._formatBuffer(type, '  '.repeat(this._groupDepth) + message),
    );
  }

  assert(...args) {
    try {
      assert(...args);
    } catch (error) {
      this._log('assert', error.toString());
    }
  }

  count(label = 'default') {
    if (!this._counters[label]) {
      this._counters[label] = 0;
    }

    this._log('count', format(`${label}: ${++this._counters[label]}`));
  }

  countReset(label = 'default') {
    this._counters[label] = 0;
  }

  debug(...args) {
    this._log('debug', format(...args));
  }

  dir(...args) {
    this._log('dir', format(...args));
  }

  dirxml(...args) {
    this._log('dirxml', format(...args));
  }

  error(...args) {
    this._log('error', format(...args));
  }

  group(...args) {
    this._groupDepth++;

    if (args.length > 0) {
      this._log('group', chalk.bold(format(...args)));
    }
  }

  groupCollapsed(...args) {
    this._groupDepth++;

    if (args.length > 0) {
      this._log('groupCollapsed', chalk.bold(format(...args)));
    }
  }

  groupEnd() {
    if (this._groupDepth > 0) {
      this._groupDepth--;
    }
  }

  info(...args) {
    this._log('info', format(...args));
  }

  log(...args) {
    this._log('log', format(...args));
  }

  time(label = 'default') {
    if (this._timers[label]) {
      return;
    }

    this._timers[label] = new Date();
  }

  timeEnd(label = 'default') {
    const startTime = this._timers[label];

    if (startTime) {
      const endTime = new Date();
      const time = endTime - startTime;
      this._log('time', format(`${label}: ${time}ms`));
      delete this._timers[label];
    }
  }

  warn(...args) {
    this._log('warn', format(...args));
  }

  getBuffer() {
    return null;
  }
}

module.exports.SimpleConsole = SimpleConsole;
```

Comment: I will try it out. Thanks so much!

Comment: Overriding the default console breaks the Jest `--silent` option

Comment: Perfect. it is was I was looking for!! Thank so much.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Haral Wellmann's answer but avoid typescript, then you can merely do something like:

```
const JestConsole = require('./node_modules/@jest/console');
global.console = new JestConsole.CustomConsole(process.stdout, process.stderr, (type, message) => {
    const TITLE_INDENT = '    ';
    const CONSOLE_INDENT = TITLE_INDENT + '  ';
    return message.split(/\n/).map(line => CONSOLE_INDENT + line).join('\n');
  });
```

Comment: Note: and if you really don't like all those annoying extra empty lines between console messages, you can consider adding `.replace(/\n$/, '')` after the `.join('\n')`.