# Setup Jasmine like console reporter

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I want to setup the console output of Jest to change its `default` output quite similar to the Jasmine output.

1. Write the `console.log` and test case results immediately
2. Remove the origin line of the `console.log` output
3. No need for parallel execution

---

Therefore I configured `{ verbose: true, maxWorkers: 1 }` and setup the environment as described in [Remove logging the origin line in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443150/846163). To report the test case results immediately, I created a custom reporter.

```
import { Test } from '@jest/reporters';
import { TestCaseResult } from '@jest/test-result';
import BaseReporter from '@jest/reporters/build/base_reporter';

class SimpleConsoleReporter extends BaseReporter {
  onTestCaseResult(test: Test, testCaseResult: TestCaseResult): Promise<void> | void {
    console.log('onTestCaseResult', testCaseResult.fullName, testCaseResult.status);
  }
}

export default SimpleConsoleReporter;
```

Finally I see the console output but no test case result using Jest `26.4.2`. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: It seems that `jest --testRunner='jest-circus/runner'` solves the problem.