# How to achieve common unit test logging best practices in jest/create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app

I'm experiment with the unit testing experience in a plain create-react-app (i.e. Jest) context. Let's assume I have tests like:

```
test('someTest', () => {
  // test something here...
  console.log("debug detail in some test")
  expect(true).toEqual(true);
});

test('someOtherTest', () => {
  // test something here...
  console.log("debug detail in some other test")
  expect(true).toEqual(false);
});
```

Running `npm test` results in a report like:

[image]

I find it very difficult to apply my TDD approaches from other languages with this kind of reporting. What I would like to achieve is a test reporting style like it is the standard in many other programming languages / ecosystems:

- I'd like a `console.log` statement to only use 1 line of vertical space, not 5 lines, without any magic indentation or decoration just like a normal print/echo in other languages. Having a log statement use up 5 lines is very impractical when having to `console.log` a bit more than a few lines.
- In other test ecosystems, it is standard to capture the output per test case, and only show the output of a failed test. This is extremely helpful, because test cases can actually be enriched with helpful debug output, which doesn't clutter the output at all on successful runs, but if a test fails, it immediately includes helpful information about its internals, which often helps to identify the failure cause right away. Jest does neither filter out successful `console.log`'s nor does it show them in context of the failed test, which mainly turns them into a nuisance.

Can this be achieved with Jest, or am I facing a fundamental limitation?

If the limitation is `console.log` itself, is there some other way of "enriching tests with output to be displayed in case of a failure"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555568/remove-logging-the-origin-line-in-jest .

Comment: As for enriching, this is the case for custom matcher or jest-expect-message.

Comment: @Estus Flask: I just find it very tedious having to couple logs to expects. A quick log here and there that is not coupled to any check would be so convenient. Also, it would be handy to (temporarily) debug print internals in the actual productive code, which probably is impossible with jest-expect-message.

Comment: Yes, it may be tedious, but console.log isn't specifically intended for what you're trying it to use. If you need debugging details rather than meaningful message, this is the case for custom matcher. Also it's unknown what's your case exactly. Most times tests need to be debugged when assertions aren't specific enough. A best practice would be to write a test in a way so that failed assertion gives a precise idea what a problem is and where. And if there's a need for debugging, console isn't meant for that too, use a real debugger.