# How do I get Jest to behave normally with console.log statements?

Tags: jestjs

I run my Jest tests in `--verbose` mode, to be able to see what my tests are outputting with `console.log`.

However, instead of just producing the original console text, Jest produces extra text too.

For example:

```
console.log("foobar")
```

Instead of producing:

```
foobar
```

Produces:

```
console.log
    foobar
```

How can I make Jest not modify my `console.log` function at all? I just want to output things as they are.

The reason I want to do it, is because the way Jest presents the log statements takes up a lot of space vertically, and is hard to read through.

Comment: Actually going direct to https://stackoverflow.com/q/51555568/3001761 is better, I've suggested that as a dupe for the one above too.