# How can I stop Jest wrapping `console.log` in test output?

Tags: jestjs, console.log

I'm making a Jest test with request

```
describe("GET /user ", () => {
    test("It should respond with a array of users", done => {
        return request(url, (err, res, body) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                console.log("GET on " + url);
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                expect(body.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
                done();
            }
        })
    })
});
```

and it's weird because in the terminal, jest is showing console.log line as  part of the output:

```
 ...test output...

  console.log test/modules/user.test.js:18
    GET on https://xpto/api/user

...more test output...
```

I need to hide the line:

```
console.log test/modules/user.test.js:18
```

How to hide console.log line in Jest output?

Comment: Seems like duplicate with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50942189/how-to-disable-jest-console-log-tags

Answer (score 24):

You can replace Jest's `console` implementation with the "normal" console like this:

```
const jestConsole = console;

beforeEach(() => {
  global.console = require('console');
});

afterEach(() => {
  global.console = jestConsole;
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Mock implementations are only useful for fully disabling logs. This method disables only Jest's tracing successfully. Than you!

Comment: For ES6 use

import console from "console";
...
const jestConsole = console;

beforeEach(() => {
  global.console = console;
});

afterEach(() => {
  global.console = jestConsole;
});

Answer (score 4):

If it's a test you've written, why do you even need to log the error? You can rely on jest assertions for that.
If you have no other solution, you can stub out the `console.log` function like so:

```js
const log = console.log;
console.log = () => {};

/** Test logic goes here **/

console.log = log; // Return things to normal so other tests aren't affected.
```

Comment: I don't know if this is hacky or not... but works really well.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your own log function with `process.stdout.write` or use it instead of `console.log` because jest is spying on all console functions.

While ago I have been trying to bring to Typescript one utility that I really like in Scala; `GivenWhenThen` annotations in tests and I encountered the same problem as you. I don't understand why `jest` prints these "consol.log + line", it doesn't make sense because you can easily find them with Crt + Find and there is no option to switch them off with --silent and --verbose=false options (of course silent will work but it will remove all log so what is the point).

Finally, I came up with:

```js
const colors = require('colors');

const testLog = (str : string) => process.stdout.write(str)

export const Given = (givenMsg: string) => testLog(`\n+ Given ${givenMsg}\n`)
export const When = (whenMsg: string) => testLog(`+ When ${whenMsg}\n`)
export const Then = (thenMsg: string) => testLog(`+ Then ${thenMsg}\n`)
export const And = (andMsg: string) => testLog(`- And ${andMsg}\n`)

export const testCase = (description: string, testFunction: Function) => it (description, () => {
    testLog(colors.yellow(`\n\nTest: ${description}\n`))
    testFunction()
    testLog('\n')
})
```

Looked like this:

[given when then typescript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABpwk.png)

Comment: This answer seems like more of a workaround than a solution - `console.log()` already works, the question is how to stop Jest from changing `console.log()`s behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) to mock the `console` methods:

```
const spy = jest.spyOn(console,'warn').mockReturnValue()

// after you are done with the test, restore the console
spy.mockRestore()
```

You can create a utility function to mock the `console`:

```
function mockConsole(method = 'warn', value){
    return jest.spyOn(console,method).mockReturnValue(value).mockRestore
}

const restore = mockConsole() //mock it

// later when you are done
restore() // unmock it
```

Also, you can combine above code answers with [jest.beforeEach](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#beforeeachfn-timeout) to automatically restore the `console`:

```
beforeEach(()=>{
    // beware that this will restore all mocks, not just the console mock
    jest.restoreAllMocks()
})
```

Comment: I think this also misses the point - the OP doesn't want any additional behaviour, but rather that the console has it's default behaviour, without jest's tracing.

Answer (score 0):

Make a file `logger-utils.ts` with following code -

```
// eslint-disable-next-line global-require, @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
export const jestLogger = require('console').log;
```

In your tests, you can use:

```
jestLogger('Hello', 'world');
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try running jest with the **--silent** argument.

In package.json, use two scripts:

```
"scripts": {
   "test": "jest --silent",
   "testVerbose": "jest"
},
```

Comment: This misses the point: it drops the actual output too.